# How do I make the following Scala code more functional and less procedural?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to wrap my head around functional programming concepts.  Consider the problem of removing empty (zero length) Strings from a list

The following is a purely functional implementation in Haskell which is very readable even if you know nothing about the language

```
removeEmpty            :: [String] -> [String]
removeEmpty []          = []
removeEmpty ([] :strs)  = removeEmpty strs
removeEmpty (str:strs)  = str : removeEmpty strs
```

Now consider my implementation in Scala

```
  def removeEmpty(dirty: List[String]): List[String] = {
    if (Nil == dirty)
      dirty
    else {
      if (dirty(0).length() == 0)
        removeEmpty(dirty.tail)
      else
        dirty.head::removeEmpty(dirty.tail)
    }
  }
```

It does the same thing but has a very procedural feel about it.  Is there a more functional way to write the same method in Scala?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
def removeEmpty(dirty: List[String]): List[String] = dirty match {
  case Nil      => Nil
  case "" :: xs => removeEmpty(xs)
  case  x :: xs => x :: removeEmpty(xs)
}
```

Dirk's answer probably contains the better solution, but my answer is closer to the original, I think.

Answer (score 8):

The first thing which came to my mind was

```
list.filter(_.length > 0)
```

Not sure, whether this meets your criterion for being “more functional“, as you did not specify, what it would mean...

Comment: computing the length is inefficient, you should just check whether it is empty

Comment: @Kim -- The OP's example uses List[String]; taking the length of a string is a simple, fast operation. If it were List[List[...]], I'd agree with you.

Comment: getting the length of a list is an O(n) operation

Comment: @Kim -- yes... But that does not change the fact, that getting the length of a string is O(1), so?

Comment: No matter what is more efficient, I think that `list.filter(!_.isEmpty)` reads better.

Comment: I'd do `list filter (_ nonEmpty)`. Or, if performance was necessary, use @zyggystar's solution, since JVM 1.6 supports `isEmpty` on `String`.